# How to detect application activation

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to perform some action when my application receives focus.

I've tried hooking both GotFocus- and Enter-events, but they only trigger when focus changes within my application.

Scenario is that my application detects some problem that must be resolved elsewhere, and I would like to do the check again when the user goes back to my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try overriding [Form.OnActivated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onactivated(VS.85).aspx) (or handling the [Form.Activated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activated(VS.85).aspx) event) in your application form.

Answer (score 1):

Try hooking the Activated event.